# Ruby Invalid Byte Sequence in UTF-8

Tags: ruby

I have the following code, which gives me an invalid byte sequence error pointing to the scan method in `initialize`. Any ideas on how to fix this? For what it's worth, the error does not occur when the `(.*)` between the h1 tag and the closing `>` is not there.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

class NewsParser

  def initialize
      Dir.glob("./**/index.htm") do |file|
        @file = IO.read file 
        parsed = @file.scan(/<h1(.*)>(.*?)<\/h1>(.*)<!-- InstanceEndEditable -->/im)
        self.write(parsed)
      end
  end

  def write output
    @contents = output
    open('output.txt', 'a') do |f| 
      f << @contents[0][0]+"\n\n"+@contents[0][1]+"\n\n\n\n" 
    end
  end

end

p = NewsParser.new
```

Edit: Here is the error message:

`news_parser.rb:10:in 'scan': invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 (ArgumentError)`

SOLVED: The combination of using:
`@file = IO.read(file).force_encoding("ISO-8859-1").encode("utf-8", replace: nil)`
and
`encoding: UTF-8`
solve the issue.

Thanks!

Comment: try `@file = IO.read(file).encode("utf-8", replace: nil)`

Comment: Nope, I get the same error message.

Comment: It looks like the html file is Western (ISO-8859-1)

Comment: possible duplicate of [ruby 1.9: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2982677/ruby-1-9-invalid-byte-sequence-in-utf-8)

Comment: `@file = IO.read(file).force_encoding("ISO-8859-1").encode("utf-8", replace: nil)` ?

Comment: Try putting `#encoding: UTF-8` as the second line in your file.

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer then accept it; it might help others in the future.

Comment: For what it's worth the [Ruby docs state](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/IO.html#method-i-read) that the stream read by IO#read is _always_ ASCII-8BIT.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The combination of using: `@file = IO.read(file).force_encoding("ISO-8859-1").encode("utf-8", replace: nil)` and `#encoding: UTF-8` solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

While this question already has an accepted answer, I found it while having the same problem with a different style of opening the file:

```
File.open(file_name).each_with_index do |line, index|
  line.gsub!(/[{}]/, "'")
  puts "#{index} #{line}"
end
```

I found that my input file was encoded in ISO-8859-1, so I changed it to the following to avoid the error:

```
File.open(file_name, 'r:ISO-8859-1:utf-8').each_with_index do |line, index|
  line.gsub!(/[{}]/, "'")
  puts "#{index} #{line}"
end
```

See the documentation for the [optional `mode` argument](https://ruby-doc.org/core/IO.html#method-c-new) of the [`File.open` method](https://ruby-doc.org/core/File.html#method-c-open) for more details.