# Unexpected error while processing request: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, image

I am getting this error when trying to pass in an image:

```
!! Unexpected error while processing request: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8
```

The weird thing is that the raise (as below) did not get executed.

My question is: how can this happen to cause this error? Has it got anything to do with the headers or the params?

Any help here will be appreciated.

```
  def create
    raise "request did get executed in code here"
    debugger
    @asset = nil
    if params && params[:asset]
      p = params[:asset]
      if p[:file]
        user_id = p[:user_id] || current_user.try(:id)
        checksum = p[:checksum] || Util.file_checksum(p[:file].path)
        if user_id.present? && checksum.present?
          options = {:taken_at => p[:taken_at] || Util.file_taken_at(p[:file].path)}
          @asset = Asset.create user_id, checksum, p[:file], p[:file].original_filename, options
        end
      end
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      if @asset && @asset.state != QueueItem::STATE_NONE
        format.html { head :no_content }
        format.json { render :json => @asset, :status => :created }
      else
        format.html { head :no_content }
        format.json { render :json => @asset.try(:errors), :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: maybe you need this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9607554/ruby-invalid-byte-sequence-in-utf-8

Comment: Have you tried using a magic comment at the top of the file: `# Encoding: utf-8`.

Comment: Old question, but I think i already had this kind of issue with Webrick. If you're using Webrick, try to use unicorn.

Comment: Did your client send chunked request? Chunked requests are sended by binary parts so your ruby web-server cann't parse entire request and fall back with this exception.

Comment: May be it is an error uploading the image
did you add :multipart => true to  the form?

Answer (score 0):

Set the very first line in your controller with this : #encoding: UTF-8