# Why do I get ArgumentError - invalid byte sequence in UTF-8?

Tags: ruby, encoding, utf-8

While trying to print `Duplicaci¾n` out of a CSV file, I get the following error:

```
ArgumentError - invalid byte sequence in UTF-8
```

I'm using Ruby 1.9.3-p362 and opening the file using:

```
CSV.foreach(fpath, headers: true) do |row|
```

How can I skip an invalid character without using iconv or `str.encode(undef: :replace, invalid: :replace, replace: '')`?

I tried answers from the following questions, but nothing worked:

- [ruby 1.9: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2982677/ruby-1-9-invalid-byte-sequence-in-utf-8)
- [Ruby Invalid Byte Sequence in UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9607554/ruby-invalid-byte-sequence-in-utf-8)
- [ruby 1.9: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2982677/ruby-1-9-invalid-byte-sequence-in-utf-8)

Comment: We need more context; Show us the code you're using to read the CSV file. Odds are good you're not opening the file right.

Comment: Just added the CSV.foreach line im using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is from the [`CSV.open` documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-open):

> You must provide a mode with an embedded Encoding designator unless your data is in Encoding::default_external(). CSV will check the Encoding of the underlying IO object (set by the mode you pass) to determine how to parse the data. You may provide a second Encoding to have the data transcoded as it is read just as you can with a normal call to IO::open(). For example, "rb:UTF-32BE:UTF-8" would read UTF-32BE data from the file but transcode it to UTF-8 before CSV parses it.

That applies to any method in CSV that opens a file.

Also start reading in the documentation at the part beginning with:

> CSV and Character Encodings (M17n or Multilingualization)

Ruby is expecting UTF-8 but is seeing characters that don't fit. I'd suspect WIN-1252 or ISO-8859-1 or a variant.