# I get error message:in `tr': invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 (ArgumentError) when I run: ruby dk.rb init

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, utf-8, tr

I have installed Ruby 1.92 in my computer, and would like to intall rails.

When I run: `gem install rails`, I get error message as below:

```
*D:\Ruby192\Devkit>gem install rails
*ERROR:  Error installing rails:
        The 'json' native gem requires installed build tools.
Please update your PATH to include build tools or download the DevKit
from 'http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads' and follow the instructions
at 'http://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit'**
```

Then I download DevKit 4.5.2 or DevKit 3.5 and try them both as:

```
D:\Ruby192\Devkit>ruby dk.rb init
```

I always get error message:

```
d:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/win32/registry.rb:175:in `tr': invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 (ArgumentError)
        from d:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/win32/registry.rb:175:in `initialize'
        from d:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/win32/registry.rb:233:in `exception'
        from d:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/win32/registry.rb:233:in `raise'
        from d:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/win32/registry.rb:233:in `check'
        from d:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/win32/registry.rb:256:in `OpenKey'
        from d:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/win32/registry.rb:387:in `open'
        from d:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/win32/registry.rb:498:in `open'
        from dk.rb:118:in `block in scan_for'
        from dk.rb:116:in `each'
        from dk.rb:116:in `scan_for'
        from dk.rb:138:in `block in installed_rubies'
        from dk.rb:138:in `collect'
        from dk.rb:138:in `installed_rubies'
        from dk.rb:146:in `init'
        from dk.rb:313:in `run'
        from dk.rb:332:in `<main>'
```

Have you guys got any suggestion on the problem？

Comment: possible duplicate of [ruby 1.9: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2982677/ruby-1-9-invalid-byte-sequence-in-utf-8)

Comment: do you have ruby or other things installed in a path with latin charecters in it?

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered the same situation. I think that you may want to install `json` library. You should use `msys.bat` and install `json` on this terminal.

1. Execute `msys.bat` in a DevKit directory -> it invokes a new terminal.
2. `gem install json` on this terminal.
3. You can continue `gem install rails`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was solved for me by clearing the `LANG` environment variable first:

```
set LANG=
ruby dk.rb init
```

The idea comes from [this question on the RubyInstaller Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/rubyinstaller/zCj6ttx_GdI/LPFdToNc4O0J).