# Regex for named value of field after a colon

Tags: c#, regex

Using c# I am trying to use regular expressions to get the value of a piece of text that appears after a colon. I know the field name, but there is a following colon that is in a variable position. The value would end at the next whitespace.

Thus:

KnownFieldName       : Value

I'd then like to place the value into a group.

I've found a number of similar questions but none that actually points me in the direction of solving this.

This is part of a larger piece of code, but basically it fits in here:

```
     foreach (var v in fieldsToParse)
                {
                    var match = Regex.Match(line, v.pattern, RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);

                    if (match.Success)
                        v.value = match.Groups[v.name].Value;
                }
```

Comment: What's the rest of your piece of text look like?

Comment: The rest may contain further fields and answers

Comment: Is it all just fields and answers, separated by newlines, or is there more to it?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11088873/regex-to-capture-colon-separated-key-value-pairs-with-multi-line-values/11090412#11090412 which handles multi-line values as well. Or, tl;dr, the Rubular demo: http://rubular.com/r/8w3X6WGq4l.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, it was a combination of my lack of knowledge of c# implementation of Regex and Regex that let me down!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex you're looking for should be something like `(?<knownfieldname>[a-zA-Z]+)(\s+):(\s+)(?<value>[a-zA-Z]+)` or `knownfieldname(\s+):(\s+)(?<value>[a-zA-Z]+)`

This presumes that KnownFieldName and Value are both only alpha characters, of course.  If numerics can come into it you may also want to add `0-9` to the ranges, or if anything but white space is really valid there you can just use the `\S` wildcard I guess.

Edited to incorporate a variable number of spaces.  Also, in light of the comments below, you might consider bookmarking both [Derek Slager's awesome Regex tester](http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx) and [this simple Regex cheat sheet](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/46/CSharp-Regular-Expressions-Cheat-Sheet).  Helps a lot with situations like this.

Comment: I need to replace the <knownfieldname> with an an actual string. How does this work with regular expressions?

Comment: @KerSplosh <knownfieldname> is just the name of that regex group.  To put it in the context of what you posted, it'd be `match.Groups["knownfieldname"].Value;`.  But if you wanted to just make that a regex literal, you can just put it in longhand - `knownfieldname : (?<value>[a-zA-Z]+)`.  Most things in regex are just interpreted literally.

Comment: Sorry, but Im still not getting any matches with this. Note the colon is a variable number of spaces after the known field.

Comment: @KerSplosh I updated my initial answer to incorporate a variable number of spaces.  As before, you can replace the first group with just a static `knownfieldname` if you want.

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks so much for being patient with me.