# How to implement solution to invalid byte sequence (UTF-8 error)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, utf-8

So, this is probably a really, really stupid question. :/ Sorry about that, I'm a total newbie. Um, I'm getting a lot of "invalid byte sequence in UTF-8" type errors. I found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2982677/ruby-1-9-invalid-byte-sequence-in-utf-8) (scroll down for the +24 one), but I have no idea how to actually implement it. Do I type it in the head of the affected files? Do I have to install anything else? Also, which solution is better, the ignore one or the double-encoding one?

Also bonus noob question! The code I'm fiddling with now is actually shared code, which means that it's presumably worked for a lot of other people without the UTF-8 problem. Any idea why my computer especially seems to be unable to get it working? Thanks.

Comment: Suggested reading: [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Comment: Hmm, I did know the basics of Unicode already, but that makes for interesting reading. The header of the file already has charset=utf-8 in it, though, so can't mess with that. Thank you though!

Answer (score 0):

Just put

```
# encoding: utf-8
```

on the very first line of affected files.