# Ruby invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 (ArgumentError)

Tags: ruby, encoding, web-crawler

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ruby 1.9: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2982677/ruby-1-9-invalid-byte-sequence-in-utf-8)

I'm currently building a file system crawler and receiving the following error when running my script:

```
wordcrawler.rb:8:in `block in <main>': invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 (ArgumentError)
    from /Users/Anconia/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/find.rb:41:in `block in find'
    from /Users/Anconia/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/find.rb:40:in `catch'
    from /Users/Anconia/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/find.rb:40:in `find'
    from wordcrawler.rb:5:in `<main>'
```

And here is my code:

```
require 'find'

count = 0

Find.find('/Users/Anconia/') do |file|                   # '/' for root directory on OS X
  if file =~ /\b(\.txt|\.doc|\.docx)\b/                # check if filename ends in desired format
    contents = File.read(file)
      if contents =~ /regex/
      puts file
      count += 1
    end
  end
end

puts "#{count} files were found"
```

In my dev environment I use ruby 1.9.3; however, when I switch to ruby 1.8.7 the script runs properly. And I'd like to continue using 1.9.3 if possible. I've tried every solution in this post ([ruby 1.9: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2982677/ruby-1-9-invalid-byte-sequence-in-utf-8)) but my problems still persist. Any suggestions?

Comment: @SeanHill as I mentioned, that post has been previously researched

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to include the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8873922/367611

Comment: So are you saying that `encode!` doesn't solve your issue?  If so, you should be more specific in your question.

Comment: @SeanHill After some hacking away on my code I got it running - feel free to remove this question

Comment: You should answer your question and then accept that as the answer.  Glad you got it working.  Cheers!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wasn't properly understanding the contents of the aforementioned post. At bare minimum this can be used as an implemented example of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8873922/367611)

```
require 'find'

count = 0

Find.find('/Users/Anconia/') do |file|                                              # '/' for root directory on OS X
  if file =~ /\b(\.txt|\.doc|\.docx)\b/                                           # check if filename ends in desired format
    contents = File.read(file).encode!('UTF-8', 'UTF-8', :invalid => :replace)    # resolves encoding errors - must use 1.9.3 else use iconv
      if contents =~ /regex/
        puts file
        count += 1
    end
  end
end

puts "#{count} files were found"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I had an issue which has been solved by using  :invalid => :replace :-)