# Ruby Filtering issue

Tags: ruby, regex

I have been trying to filter some text from a file to only show certain years of birth

I have some ruby that reads in a file ages.txt, it contains names and years of birth

- Joe Bloggs (2001)
- Mary Bloggs (1987)
- John apples (2010)
- Old Guy (1990)

I wish to be able to filter for a year range, i.e. to find people born between 1987 and 1990

I have tried

```
#open('ages.txt') { |f| f.grep(/^19(8[0-9]|10)$/) }
```

but I get an error

```
ages.rb:3:in `===': invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 (ArgumentError)
```

Any help would be greatfull.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `^` and the `$` make the expression try to match whole lines, which will not work.

Try: `/19(8[7-9]|90)/`

[Here](http://rubular.com/r/Z94eDybP19) is a working version. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Your answer should be here, not (only) on Rubular.

Comment: Added it in, sorry about that

Comment: It looks like that is an encoding problem. Have a look at [this question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2982677/ruby-1-9-invalid-byte-sequence-in-utf-8/8873922#8873922).