# How to convert a string to UTF8 in Ruby

Tags: ruby, file, encoding, utf-8, dump

I'm writing a crawler which uses Hpricot. It downloads a list of strings from some webpage, then I try to write it to the file. Something is wrong with the encoding:

```
"\xC3" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8
```

I have items which are rendered on a webpage and printed this way:

```
DÃ©veloppement
```

the `str.encoding` returns `UTF-8`, so `force_encoding('UTF-8')` doesn't help. How may I convert this to readable UTF-8?

Comment: Hpricot is no longer maintained, consider using Nokogiri. Also, you should probably mention what the encoding of the original web page is.

Answer (score 73):

Your string seems to have been encoded the wrong way round:

```
"DÃ©veloppement".encode("iso-8859-1").force_encoding("utf-8")
#=> "Développement"
```

Comment: It works good for most of cases. But sometimes: `U+201C from UTF-8 to ISO-8859-1 in CIDEM / ACC1Ã“`
`U+20AC from UTF-8 to ISO-8859-1 in Citiâ€™s Sustainable Development Investments` it doesn't. Also some names are converted but wrong and I can't seed it in a database with `incomplete multibyte character` error message

Comment: Sorry, this was not meant as a fix. You should fix the problem by setting/detecting the correct encoding when reading the strings into your app.

Comment: There is also the option of using `Encoding::UTF_8` instead of using more memory for the `"utf-8"` string literal (or any other encoding string).

Answer (score 61):

Seems your string thinks it is UTF-8, but in reality, it is something else, probably ISO-8859-1.

Define (force) the correct encoding first, then convert it to UTF-8.

In your example:

```
puts "DÃ©veloppement".encode('iso-8859-1').encode('utf-8')
```

An alternative is:

```
puts "\xC3".force_encoding('iso-8859-1').encode('utf-8') #-> Ã
```

If the `Ã` makes no sense, then try another encoding.

Comment: Works for pdfs created with Wicked PDF gem

Answer (score 6):

"[ruby 1.9: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2982677/ruby-1-9-invalid-byte-sequence-in-utf-8?rq=1)" described another good approach with less code:

```
file_contents.encode!('UTF-16', 'UTF-8')
```