# Encoding::UndefinedConversionError: "\xC2" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I received the following error upon saving a new contact. Is there a way to cast `"\xC2"` so that it can be forced to be saved in the UTF-8 format?

```
c = Contact.new
c.save!
```

> Encoding::UndefinedConversionError: "\xC2" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8: INSERT INTO "contacts" ("body", "created_at", "email", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Your string is in some other encoding, most likely iso-8859-1, so you should run this to convert it:

```
"\xC2".encode("iso-8859-1").force_encoding("utf-8")
=> "Ã"
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17022394/convert-string-to-utf8-in-ruby) for more information related to this issue.

Comment: Was flailing around converting some code that used HtmlEntities from 1.8.7 to 1.9.3 — This helped. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

For what it's worth, I had this issue pop up when I read in a code file that had the degree symbol (°) in a comment. Upon encoding it for json, ruby became incredibly unhappy.

What threw me for a loop was that there wasn't a "Ã" character in the code, so it's just something to keep in mind.