# How to check if a string contains ASCII code

Tags: ruby, string, utf-8

Given a string `A\xC3B`, it can be converted to utf-8 string by doing this (ref [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17022394/convert-string-to-utf8-in-ruby/17026362#17026362)):

```
"A\xC3B".force_encoding('iso-8859-1').encode('utf-8') #=> "AÃB"
```

However, I only want to perform the action if the string contains the ASCII code, namely `\xC3`. How can I check for that?

Tried `"A\xC3B".include?("\x")` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`\x` is just a hexadecimal escape sequence. It has nothing to do with encodings on its own. US-ASCII goes from `"\x00"` to `"\x7F"` (e.g. `"\x41"` is the same as `"A"`, `"\x30"` is `"0"`). The rest (`"\x80"` to `"\xFF"`) however are not US-ASCII characters since it's a 7-bit character set.

If you want to check if a string contains only US-ASCII characters, call [`String#ascii_only?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-ascii_only-3F):

```
p "A\xC3B".ascii_only? # => false
p "\x41BC".ascii_only? # => true
```

Another example based on your code:

```
str = "A\xC3B"
unless str.ascii_only?
  str.force_encoding(Encoding::ISO_8859_1).encode!(Encoding::UTF_8)
end
p str.encoding # => #<Encoding:UTF-8>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want to do is to figure out whether your string is properly encoded. The `ascii_only?` solution isn't much help when dealing with non-Ascii strings.

I would use [`String#valid_encoding?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/String.html#method-i-valid_encoding-3F) to verify whether a string is properly encoded, even if it contains non-ASCII chars.

For example, what if someone else has encoded `"Françoise Paré"` the right way, and when I decode it I get the right string instead of `"Fran\xE7oise Par\xE9"` (which is what would be decoded if someone encoded it into ISO-8859-1).

```
[62] pry(main)> "Françoise Paré".encode("utf-8").valid_encoding?
=> true

[63] pry(main)> "Françoise Paré".encode("iso-8859-1")
=> "Fran\xE7oise Par\xE9"

# Note the encoding is still valid, it's just the way IRB displays
# ISO-8859-1

[64] pry(main)> "Françoise Paré".encode("iso-8859-1").valid_encoding?
=> true

# Now let's interpret our 8859 string as UTF-8. In the following
# line, the string bytes don't change, `force_encoding` just makes
# Ruby interpret those same bytes as UTF-8.

[65] pry(main)> "Françoise Paré".encode("iso-8859-1").force_encoding("utf-8")
=> "Fran\xE7oise Par\xE9"

# Is a lone \xE7 valid UTF-8? Nope.

[66] pry(main)> "Françoise Paré".encode("iso-8859-1").force_encoding("utf-8").valid_encoding?
=> false
```