# How to decrypt a String saved in a mongoDB Mongoid::EncryptedStringRandomSalt

Tags: ruby, mongodb

I have a string that was encrypted in our MongoDB. It is saved with some encoded characters like  ö  using Mongoid::EncryptedStringRandomSalt.

When the page loads the data I get an error. I cannot delete the data as it is a customers data.

```
 ActionView::Template::Error (incompatible character encodings: ASCII-8BIT and UTF-8): 
<td><%= simple_format(row.notes,{}, :sanitize => false).html_safe? %></td>
```

I need to decrypt the data copy out the good characters and replace the encrypted data with the good characters.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17022394/how-to-convert-a-string-to-utf8-in-ruby ?

Comment: Google has no mentions of `EncryptedStringRandomSalt` whatsoever (apart from this very question). Care for any additional details?