# How to decode utf8 characters with ruby Base64

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Just as the title describes, how can I do the following?

```
require 'base64'

text = 'éééé'
encode = Base64.encode64(text)
Base64.decode64(encode)

Result: éééé instead of \xC3\xA9\xC3\xA9
```

Comment: This answer might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/17023810/7619578

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you `decode64` you get back a string with `BINARY` (a.k.a. `ASCII-8BIT`) encoding:

```rb
Base64.decode64(encode).encoding
# => #<Encoding:ASCII-8BIT>
```

The trick is to force-apply a particular encoding:

```rb
Base64.decode64(encode).force_encoding('UTF-8')
# => "éééé"
```

This assumes that your string is valid UTF-8, which it might not be, so use with caution.

Answer (score 0):

Just use Base64's `encode` and `decode` method:

```
require 'base64'
=> true
Base64.encode64('aksdfjd')
=> "YWtzZGZqZA==\n"

Base64.decode64 "YWtzZGZqZA==\n"
=> "aksdfjd"
```