# Encoding UTF-8 Characters with base 64

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hello I need to encode a string with `'Ñ'`
I'm doing a connection with a provider sending this data `Base64.encode64('Muñoz')` for example but when the provider decode this string he see this string `"Mu\xC3\xB1os"`, How I can encode correctly the string?

```
Base64.encode64('Muñoz')
Base64.decode64(base64) == Muñoz
```

Comment: `Base64.decode64(Base64.encode64('Muñoz')).force_encoding('UTF-8') == 'Muñoz' #=> true`

Answer (score 0):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66591595/how-to-decode-utf8-characters-with-ruby-base64), which describes the encoding issue you are seeing, along with a solution using `force_encoding`:

```rb
Base64.decode64(encode).force_encoding('UTF-8')
```