# How to create a string with a "bad encoding" in ruby?

Tags: ruby, character-encoding

I have a file somewhere out in production that I *do not* have access to that, when loaded by a ruby script, a regular expression against the contents fails with a `ArgumentError => invalid byte sequence in UTF-8`.

I believe I have a fix based on the answer with all the points here: [ruby 1.9: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2982677/ruby-1-9-invalid-byte-sequence-in-utf-8)

```
# Remove all invalid and undefined characters in the given string
# (ruby 1.9.3)
def safe_str str

  # edited based on matt's comment (thanks matt)
  s = str.encode('utf-16', 'utf-8', invalid: :replace, undef: :replace, replace: '')
  s.encode!('utf-8', 'utf-16')
end
```

However, I now want to build my rspec to verify that the code works. I don't have access to the file that caused the problem so I want to create a string with the bad encoding programatically.

I've tried variations on things like:

```
bad_str = (100..1000).to_a.inject('') {|s,c| s << c; s}
bad_str.length.should > safe_str(bad_str).length
```

or,

```
bad_str = (100..1000).to_a.pack(c*)
bad_str.length.should > safe_str(bad_str).length
```

but the length is always the same. I have also tried different character ranges; not always 100 to 1000.

Any suggestions on how to build a string with an invalid encoding within a ruby 1.9.3 script?

Comment: Do your bad strings trigger the original "invalid byte sequence" exception?  Maybe they really are bad, but `safe_str` is not catching it for some reason.

Comment: Thanks @HewWolff I havn't deployed it yet. I wanted to get my tests to behave properly (which is a good thing based on matt's comment below).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `safe_str` method will (currently) never actually do anything to the string, it is a no-op. The docs for [`String#encode` on Ruby 1.9.3 say](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-encode):

> Please note that conversion from an encoding enc to the same encoding enc is a no-op, i.e. the receiver is returned without any changes, and no exceptions are raised, even if there are invalid bytes.

This is true for the current release of 2.0.0 (patch level 247), however a [recent commit to Ruby trunk](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/commit/394d5dfa9ba625c99a1e6a411f81b628bfebd60a) changes this, and also introduces a `scrub` method that pretty much does what you want.

Until a new version of Ruby is released you will need to round trip your text string to another encoding and back to clean it, as in the second example in [this answer to the question you linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8873922/214790), something like:

```
def safe_str str
  s = str.encode('utf-16', 'utf-8', invalid: :replace, undef: :replace, replace: '')
  s.encode!('utf-8', 'utf-16')
end
```

Note that your first example of an attempt to create an invalid string won’t work:

```
bad_str = (100..1000).to_a.inject('') {|s,c| s << c; s}
bad_str.valid_encoding? # => true
```

From the [`<<` docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-3C-3C):

> If the object is a Integer, it is considered as a codepoint, and is converted to a character before concatenation.

So you’ll always get a valid string.

Your second method, using `pack` will create a string with the encoding `ASCII-8BIT`. If you then change this using [`force_encoding`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-force_encoding) you can create a UTF-8 string with an invalid encoding:

```
bad_str = (100..1000).to_a.pack('c*').force_encoding('utf-8')
bad_str.valid_encoding? # => false
```

Comment: Thank you. It was the `force_encoding` step that was consistently throwing me off.

Comment: P.S. I wish I had access to ruby 2. The `scrub` method is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 5):

Lots of one-byte strings will make an invalid UTF-8 string, starting with 0x80.  So `128.chr` should work.

Comment: Thank you. I forgot about the `chr` method on `Integer`.

Answer (score 3):

Try with `s = "hi \255"`

```rb
s.valid_encoding?
# => false
```

Answer (score 1):

Following example can be used for testing purposes:

```rb
describe TestClass do
  let(:non_utf8_text) { "something\255 english." }

  it 'is not raise error on invalid byte sequence string' do
    expect(non_utf8_text).not_to be_valid_encoding
    expect { subject.call(non_utf8_text) }.not_to raise_error
  end
end
```

Thanks to Iwan B. for "\255" advise.

Answer (score 0):

In spec tests I’ve written, I haven’t found a way to fix this bad encoding:

> Period%Basics

The `%B` string consistently produces `ArgumentError: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8`.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the '%'? Are you using that to indicate a hex value like `"Period\xBasics"`?

Comment: I haven’t even bothered to check what the value maps to or what it represents. I became aware of the string by checking Airbrake exceptions and the bad string came from a GET param. I tried a variety of ways to catch or fix the exception, but didn’t have luck.