# Ruby 1.9.3 Invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 explanation needed

Tags: ruby, utf-8, rvm, encode

I installed RVM and Ruby through Cygwin on Windows 7. I am now trying to install Omega bundle following [this guide](https://drupal.org/node/2138087). The command is

```
bundle install
```

Which gives an error 'command not found'. The solution for this is to install bundler via

```
gem install bundler
```

But this gives an 'Invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 error'. The solution for this is described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2982677/ruby-1-9-invalid-byte-sequence-in-utf-8/8873922#8873922). But I don't understand where I should place this snippet.

```
require 'iconv' unless String.method_defined?(:encode)
if String.method_defined?(:encode)
  file_contents.encode!('UTF-8', 'UTF-8', :invalid => :replace)
else
  ic = Iconv.new('UTF-8', 'UTF-8//IGNORE')
  file_contents = ic.iconv(file_contents)
end
```

Please explain where to put this code in.

Thank you!

Comment: This error message during `gem install ...` usually indicates a problem auto-generating documentation, but the gem should actually be installed. I usually ignore the message and use online documentation for affected gems.

Comment: Hi Nick. Unfortunately the gem is not installed, as 'bundle install' still doesn't work.

Comment: Did you perform the `gem install` in the root folder of your project (this may be necessary as `rvm` can switch Ruby versions automagically, so your install might go to one Ruby when you meant another...). Alternatively, is your error message "Bundler::GemfileNotFound"? That means something different . . .

Comment: Hello, yes I tried installing in the root folder (where cygwin opens by default). The error I'm getting reads: ERROR: while executing gem ... (ArgumentError) invalid byte sequence in UTF-8.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have 64 bit Cygwin, Ruby 2.0.0 and gem 2.4.1 and was experiencing the same issue. `gem install ...`, `gem update`, everything ended with "*ERROR:  While executing gem ... (ArgumentError) invalid byte sequence in UTF-8*".

I had also all locales set to "*en_US.UTF-8*".

I have read somewhere that it should help to set `LANG` to an empty string or "*C.BINARY*", but it didn't help. But it was good hint to start experimenting.

**Finally I have solved that by setting both `LANG` and `LC_ALL` to an empty string.** All other locale environment variables (`LC_CTYPE` etc.) was automatically set to "C.UTF-8" by that, `LANG` and `LC_ALL` remained empty.

Now `gem` is finally working.

---

#### UPDATE

It seems that specifically `LC_CTYPE` is causing that issue if it's set to *UTF-8*. So setting it to *C.BINARY* should help. Other locale environment variables can be set to *UTF-8* without affecting it.

`export LC_CTYPE=C.BINARY`

Comment: Setting `LC_CTYPE=C.BINARY` solved the problem, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Just set character to something other than UTF-8 of Cygwin

Click left top icon --> Options --> Text --> set "Character set" to something (e.g. GBK)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, it has worked for me:

```
> $ LANG=C.BINARY gem install bundler
```

You can find out more information [here](https://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2014-09/msg00098.html)