# Ruby Compiling errors

Tags: ruby, cygwin, notepad++

I am currently writing code in Notepad++ and running it using Cygwin Terminal. I heard that cygwin is very strict about indenting and spaces so I used an online formatter and formatted my code. This is my formatted code:

```
    open("Safeway.html"){ 
    |f|f.each_line.find_all{|line|/"\/recipe\//.match(
    line)}.map {|line| line.split [4..5].join(' ')} }
```

I am running into this error:

```
Scraper.rb.txt:2:in `match': invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 (ArgumentError)
    from Scraper.rb.txt:2:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
    from Scraper.rb.txt:2:in `each_line'
    from Scraper.rb.txt:2:in `each'
    from Scraper.rb.txt:2:in `find_all'
    from Scraper.rb.txt:2:in `block in <main>'
    from Scraper.rb.txt:1:in `open'
    from Scraper.rb.txt:1:in `<main>'
```

What does this error mean and how can I fix it?

Comment: Please don't completely change the topic and content of your question with an edit _after_ people have answered it. Just ask a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem is in the *contents* of the `"Safeway.html"` file.

I suggest that you print each line before running the `match` on it, and see on which line the exceptions occurs:

```
open("Safeway.html") do |f|
  f.each_line.find_all do |line|
    puts line
    /"\/recipe\//.match(line)
  end.map {|line| line.split [4..5].join(' ')}
end
```

The lines which is printed just before the exception is thrown (or maybe the one after it) is the problematic one - does it have weird characters in it? maybe invisible characters?

Answer (score 0):

Ruby is very fussy about newlines when you are using blocks.  If you reformat what you have above as

```
open("Safeway.html"){ |f| f.each_line.find_all { |line| /"\/recipe\//.match(line) }.map { |line| line.split [4..5].join(' ') } }
```

it works.

If you reformat it as

```
open("Safeway.html"){ |f| 
  f.each_line.find_all { |line| 
    /"\/recipe\//.match(line) 
  }.map { |line| 
    line.split [4..5].join(' ') 
  } 
}
```

It also seems to parse fine.

Basically, just be more careful about where you put your linebreaks.

Comment: When I run your reformatted code I get t his error:  scraper.rb.txt:3:in `match': invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 (ArgumentError)
        from scraper.rb.txt:3:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
        from scraper.rb.txt:2:in `each_line'
        from scraper.rb.txt:2:in `each'
        from scraper.rb.txt:2:in `find_all'
        from scraper.rb.txt:2:in `block in <main>'
        from scraper.rb.txt:1:in `open'
        from scraper.rb.txt:1:in `<main>'

Comment: That is a character encoding issue in your input file.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2982677/ruby-1-9-invalid-byte-sequence-in-utf-8

Comment: What is a character encoding issue and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

In Ruby, a newline indicates the end of statement *unless there is some unclosed syntax present*.

When the interpreter reads

```
open("Safeway.html")
```

It sees a method call. Done. On to the next line. The first thing it sees there is `{` and it thinks, "Ah, this must be a Hash literal". But then it sees `|` which has no place in a Hash literal. That's a syntax error. If you move the `{` to the end of the previous line, Ruby understands that it is a block, not a Hash.

At the end of that line is

```
/"\/recipe\//.match
```

Again, it sees this as a method call with no arguments. Done. But it doesn't even get to the next line because `match` requires arguments! That's an argument error. Again, just move the `(` from the next line to this one.

Comment: Here is my revised code with your edits:                            open("Safeway.html"){
|f|f.each_line.find_all{|line|/"\/recipe\//.match(
line)}.map {|line| line.split [4..5].join(' ')} }                                                                         I am still recieving the same error

Comment: Don't put code in comments. Append it to your question, and format it so it's readable and easily visible to everyone helping answer the question.