# Why do I get invalid byte sequence in UTF-8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Why do I get this error ?

```
invalid byte sequence in UTF-8
```

for loading an image in:

```
= image_tag 'features_home/show1.png'
```

**EDIT**

I've notice that this issue occurred only after I did `bundle update`, the error occurs with any image.. I will try to add details here:

Stacktrace:

```
  Rendered home/home.html.haml within layouts/application (229.9ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1047ms
invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 excluded from capture: DSN not set

ActionView::Template::Error (invalid byte sequence in UTF-8):
    81:           / Carousel items
    82:           .carousel-inner
    83:             .active.item
    84:               = image_tag 'features_home/show1.png'
    85:               -#.carousel-caption
    86:               -#  %h4
    87:               -#  %p
  app/views/home/home.html.haml:84:in `block in _app_views_home_home_html_haml__623651309533727079_70331260863620'
  app/views/home/home.html.haml:33:in `_app_views_home_home_html_haml__623651309533727079_70331260863620'
  lib/rack/seoredirect.rb:20:in `call'


  Rendered /Users/Apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@myapp/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (115.6ms)
  Rendered /Users/Apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@myapp/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (23.1ms)
  Rendered /Users/Apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@myapp/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (1.7ms)
  Rendered /Users/Apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@myapp/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/template_error.html.erb within rescues/layout (237.9ms)
```

Gemfile.lock before and after `bundle update`: https://gist.github.com/hopewise/35c2a98b13ac646b65770feb2f3c7ec8

Full trace:
https://gist.github.com/hopewise/551169518a5938647dc767d3de393cd4

I don't know which gem caused the issue though..

Comment: Probably, this is relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2982677/ruby-1-9-invalid-byte-sequence-in-utf-8

Comment: Is it possible that you have a hidden control character in your file source file? Try deleting the line and retyping it manually...

Comment: @Myst no hidden control character in the source file..

Comment: Does it happen with any image? What Ruby/Rails versions?

Comment: Could you please add a stacktrace?

Comment: RoR version 4.2.0, please check edit above

Comment: Does it happen with ERB as well? With HAML, have you tried using `%img` with `image_path`?

Comment: I did not try ERB, as for haml, I include image as `= image_tag 'features_home/show1.png'`

Comment: Does it happen with other format, like jpg images?

Comment: Yes, also jpg images will cause `invalid byte sequence in UTF-8`

Comment: Most likely not, the problem is solved, but did not know how, as I've got tons of tasks to handle at that time, I didn't have the time to investigate about it

Comment: Simo, apologies--I wasn't notified of your comment. Sorry I couldn't offer more help. I understand--thanks for taking the time to respond. I'll clean up these comments.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a bug in the `less-rails` gem that Haml uses to resolve paths for the `image_tag` directive.

When invoking `image_tag`, `less-rails` eventually attempts to scan for assets that the file depends on but may inadvertently consume non-text files. This results in the error you experience.

A [fix exists](https://github.com/metaskills/less-rails/commit/c34a9dc78b793a2f31e1917065f36f7201608365) on a (somewhat outdated) branch in the project that verifies the path correctly. We can pull in for testing:

```
gem 'less-rails', github: 'metaskills/less-rails', branch: 'depends_only_on_less_files'
```

Please see [this ticket](https://github.com/metaskills/less-rails/issues/114) for more detailed information. As suggested there, you may need to verify that the code uses an appropriate path for the image.