# Parameters in String encode method in Ruby

Tags: ruby, utf-8, ascii

Related to this [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18454435/9918823). What is meant by `binary` here? Knows it is related to **source format** but not sure whether it is **ASCII-8BIT**.

```
string.encode!('UTF-8', 'binary', invalid: :replace, undef: :replace, replace: '')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With two positional arguments, they specify *destination* and *source* encoding respectively.

`'binary'` is an alias for `'ASCII-8BIT'`:

```
Encoding::BINARY.names
#=> ["ASCII-8BIT", "BINARY"]
```

Note that you can omit the second argument (`'binary'`) if your string is already in binary encoding.